# Android Volley request works on emulator but getting client error on the physical phone. guys please help me , I am new to this

Tags: android, android-volley

Volley request is working just fine on the phone and emulator for the login activity but not for this one. See the error message and code below.

2021-02-20 22:23:25.695 29250-30267/com.bignerdranch.android.equipmentinspection E/Volley: [2336] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://sbmequipmentinspection.com/vehicleTable.php
2021-02-20 22:23:25.697 29250-29250/com.bignerdranch.android.equipmentinspection E/somethingWrong: com.android.volley.ClientError

````
private void uploadTOServer() {
      String reg_url = "https://sbmequipmentinspection.com/vehicleTable.php";
      final String loclaTime = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", mVehicle.getDate()).toString();
      StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, reg_url,
              new Response.Listener<String>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Thank you for submitting vehicle inspection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
              },
              new Response.ErrorListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("somethingWrong", error.toString());
                    Toast.makeText( getContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
              }){
         @Override
         protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
             String image = getStringImage(mPhotoFile);


            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("id", mVehicle.getID().toString());
            params.put("user", SavePreference.getPrefUserName(getActivity()));
            params.put("date",loclaTime);
            params.put("vehicleNumber",mVehicle.getEquipmentNumber());
            params.put("mileageNumber", mVehicle.getMilage());



            params.put("question1" , mQuestionBank[0].getStatus());
            params.put("question2", mQuestionBank[1].getStatus());
            params.put("question3" , mQuestionBank[2].getStatus() );
            params.put("question4", mQuestionBank[3].getStatus());
            params.put("question5", mQuestionBank[4].getStatus());
            params.put("question6", mQuestionBank[5].getStatus());
            params.put("question7", mQuestionBank[6].getStatus());
            params.put("question8", mQuestionBank[7].getStatus());
            params.put("question9", mQuestionBank[8].getStatus());
            params.put("question10", mQuestionBank[9].getStatus());
            params.put("question11", mQuestionBank[10].getStatus());
            params.put("question12", mQuestionBank[11].getStatus());
            params.put("question13", mQuestionBank[12].getStatus());
            params.put("addInfo", mVehicle.getExtraInfo());
            params.put("status", mVehicle.getStatus());

            params.put("image", image);


            return params;
         }

      };


      RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
      stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0,
              DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
              DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

      requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

   }

   private String getStringImage(File photoFile) {
      Bitmap bitmap = PictureUtils.getScaledBitmap(photoFile.getPath(),getActivity());
      ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,ba);
      byte[] imagebyte = ba.toByteArray();
      String encode = Base64.encodeToString(imagebyte, Base64.DEFAULT);
      return encode;
    
   }```
````

Comment: `Unexpected response code 404`

Comment: Why don't I get a 404 response code when I use the emulator to run the app?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do. Firstly before the return I would create a string to check the JSON format,  `String mRequestBody = jsonObject.toString();` After that i would extract that JSON and put it into an Application known as Postman, https://www.postman.com/ and test if it still works there, let me know what you find?

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help. Question: how do I extract JSON? I didn't create a JSON request and the response isn't in JASON format either? Please show me how to do exactly what you suggested.

Comment: Well dependent upon the data type your wanting to send (standard being JSON) you can define this in the getBody     @Override
    public byte[] getBody()
    {
        byte[] body;
        body = mRequestBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return body;
    }

Comment: I am trying to send string values and one picture. I am trying to insert those into remote database. Everything works fine when I use the emulator but I get an unexplained client error when I try it on my phone. Please look at the code I posted again? did I miss anything?